# What is the APIBaseURL in Bitrise's New Android Virtual Device Testing

Tags: android, bitrise

The article [here](https://blog.bitrise.io/introducing-solid-and-snappy-virtual-device-testing-for-android) doesn't mention anything related to APIBaseURL... the instrumentation test would result in:

[Issue with APIBaseURL: parameter not specified]

Anyone has any idea what the APIBaseURL means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding to the step.yml([step.yml#L259](https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-virtual-device-testing-for-android/blob/master/step.yml#L259)), the default value for the `api_base_url` input is `$ADDON_VDTESTING_API_URL`.

Usually if an environment variable is given as the default value that means it's value is exported internally. (also `is_dont_change_value: true` validates this)

If you have the default input `$ADDON_VDTESTING_API_URL` in your step, then there is an issue with something else.

The main reason can cause `$ADDON_VDTESTING_API_URL` being empty:

1) You've used the previous version of the step (maybe in the PRIVATE-BETA period) and now you've replaced the step to the new on in your workflow.

2) Maybe you forgot to turn on **Virtual Device Testing for Android** option in your app's settings tab.

A quick solution for 1) would be after going to your app's settings tab, turn off and then back on **Virtual Device Testing for Android** option.

If the issue is still exists, worth to contact Bitrise on their on-site chat and ask someone to fix it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! i forgot to turn on the settings. Would it be better once user added the step, the settings is turned on automatically? Since we are used to just add a new step in the workflow.